# best way to store the long list of values

Tags: arrays, list, powershell, hashtable, sorting

I need to store a list of processed network file shares (keeping the full UNC path) in memory so I do not process these folders again.

I was going to use an array but now I am thinking that a hashtable might be a faster option. I will need to check in a few places if that folder path (string value) exists already.

What what be the fastest (to check for an existence of that value) and less memory consuming option?

1. Store folder paths in a hashtable with an key=folder path and an empty value
2. Store folder paths in a one dimensional array
3. Something else

UPDATE:
I just ran a few tests like in that thread pointed below by generating 50000 strings and doing 3 lookups. I also looked at memory consumption and HashSet is a winner. HashTable is still a good option but Array is the worst one.

Array - 125048 ms to create, 37 ms to lookup, 18Mb in RAM

Hash -  2167 ms to create, 0.74 ms to lookup, 2.4Mb in RAM

HashSet - **1966** ms to create, **0.02** ms to lookup, **1.4Mb** in RAM

Comment: How big do you expect your list to be?

Comment: tens of thousands folders easily

Comment: Are your paths in a text file or coming from somewhere else?

Comment: i build the list of folders first as a part of my script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hastable is preferable over an array in this situation as you are going to be querying for the keys after populating it and the number of items is relatively large. I would start with a hashtable. If the performance is not suitable, then try something else, like utilizing .net's [Dictionary(T,V)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or .net 3.5+'s [HashSet(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Also, here is a link that will be of interest to you:

[Powershell 2 and .NET: Optimize for extremely large hash tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523143/powershell-2-and-net-optimize-for-extremely-large-hash-tables)

Comment: thanks for the ideas and the link - I did not realize that inserts to hash takes most of the time. I am testing this now...

Comment: i have updated the question with results of my tests - hashset is a winner!