# Populating very large hashtables - how to do so most efficiently?

Tags: performance, powershell, hashtable

***Background/Context:***

I'm having to cross-check / compare multiple data-sets (which have a tendency to be mutually inconsistent), in order to identify "item X from dataset A matches item Y or Z from dataset B".

Those datasets involved are somewhat large (100k records) and involve me poking a SQL Database.

After some initial research & performance testing, I've switched from parsing through "massive arrays" to using effectively "Indexing hashtables" for key attribute points.

***Challenge:***

Using Hashtables is *VERY* fast once you get to use them ... but my issue is in CONSTRUCTING them efficiently. It feels like I'm "nearly there", but having to resort to a (relatively) slow method (50,000 records take about 300-400 seconds).

Here's what the basic data I'm trying to index looks like at this point (I'm getting a list of distinct device names from SQL along with the counts for how many records it has for said device):

```
DEVICENAME      COUNTOF
==========      ========
DEVICE_1        1
DEVICE_2        1
DEVICE_3        2
....            ...
DEVICE_49999    3
DEVICE_50000    1
```

***Current solution:***

I'm presently constructing my hashtable by looping through the result-set (an array that I pulled out of SQL as a result set) and using ".add" for each line item.

So just a simple ...

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt @($SQL_Results).CountOf; $i++) {
    $MyIndexHash.Add( @($SQL_Results[$i]).DeviceName,  @($SQL_Results[$i]).CountOf)
}
```

This is "a bit slow" comparatively speaking (aforementioned 300-400 seconds to build the 50,000 line items). I *CAN* wait if need be, but since (on a hunch) I tried the following which was "near instant", it teased that there may be a better way to do it (took around 3 seconds).

```
$MyIndexHash.Keys = $SQL_Results.DEVICENAME
```

However - this *ONLY* populated the KEYS for the hashtable, not the associated values. And I've not figured out a way to effectively achieve the following (mass-assigning the values out of my array straight into a hashtable):

```
$MyIndexHash.Keys = ($SQL_Results.DEVICENAME, $SQL_Results.COUNTOF)
```

This is a "pure performance" question -- as some of the other comparisons I'll need to do will be with 80,000 and 150,000 lineitems. If I have to "just wait" for the hashtables to be constructed by looping through each line of my SQL results array, so be it.

**NOTE** - I have looked at - [Powershell 2 and .NET: Optimize for extremely large hash tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523143/powershell-2-and-net-optimize-for-extremely-large-hash-tables/7621762#7621762) - but since I have variable (well - "unknown but likely large") datasets to handle I'm not sure I can / want to start breaking the hashtables up.

Also, The LOOKUP in the hashtables (once populated) is super-fast after all ... it's JUST the constructing of the hashtables that I'd hope can be done in a more efficient manner somehow?

Any suggestions on how I could improve constructing the hashtables more efficiently would be welcome.

Thanks!

***UPDATE / Investigations***

Based on the comments of how quickly hash-table assignment should be by @Pawel_Dyl had me do some investigating with variations of my code and a larger (200k line item) set of data values.

Here are the results from the tests along with durations:

```
#Create the Demo Data... 200k lines
$Src = 1..200000 | % { [pscustomobject]@{Name="Item_$_"; CountOf=$_} }

# Test # 1 - Checking (... -lt $Src.Count) option vs (... -lt @($Src)Count ) ...
# Test 1A - using $Src.CountOf
$timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
$hash1A = @{}
foreach ($i in $Src) { $hash1A[$i.Name] = $i.CountOf }
$Timer.Stop()
$Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds
# Duration = 736 ms

# Now with @()
$timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
$hash1B = @{}
foreach ($i in @($Src)) { $hash1B[$i.Name] = $i.CountOf }
$Timer.Stop()
$Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds
# Duration = 728 ms

##################

# Test # 2 - Checking (... -lt $Src.Count) option vs (... -lt @($Src).Count ) ...

$timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
$hash2A = @{}
for ($i=0; $i -lt @($Src).Count; $i++) {
    $hash2A.Add(@($Src[$i]).Name, @($Src[$i]).CountOf)
}
$Timer.Stop()
$Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds
# Duration == 4,625,755 (!) (commas added for easier readability!

$timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
$hash2B = @{}
for ($i=0; $i -lt $Src.Count; $i++) {
    $hash2B.Add( $Src[$i].Name, $Src[$i].CountOf )
}
$Timer.Stop()
$Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds
# Duration == 1788 ms
```

So the problem comes by using @()-s to reference the array within the loop. Meant as a safeguard against 1-line arrays / results from SQL (which for some weird reason Powershell doesn't have as a concept, and instead treats entirely differently as a DATAOBJECT and not an array (so things like .Count aren't available without forcing POSH to handle it as an array via @() ).

So the solution "for now" is to add a simple...
    If (@($MyArray).Count -eq 1) {Do stuff with @() }
    ElseIf (@($MyArray).Count -gt 1) {Do stuff without using @()-s }

There we have our culprit - using @()-s within the loop took nearly 1.25 hours compared to ~1 second for the same operation.

Changing that has sped up things MASSIVELY (to the tune of needing only 0.1 second to construct each hashtable, even with 90,000+ objects handled "in anger". Slightly less convenient for the code, but oh well. I still don't get why Powershell has a problem with the concept of "1-line arrays" and decides to handle those differently / as a separate datatype, but there you go.

I'll still check out into the DataReader suggestions, to see where / how I can best make use of them in the code as a future improvement. Many thanks for all the advice & the great explanations to make sense of everything!

Comment: `Keys` is not actually a settable property. When you write `$MyIndexHash.Keys = $SQL_Results.DEVICENAME`, all you're doing is forcing `$SQL_Results.DEVICENAME` into an array, and then you set the hash key named `Keys` to this value -- so that's a slightly misleading metric. Given that this already takes 3 seconds, I have to wonder: what's the type of `$SQL_Results`, and are you sure it's not the continuous evaluation of `@($SQL_Results).Count` that's the problem? How long does the loop take if it's empty?

Comment: Just to clarify - are you asking me to check assigning the whole array-results with NULL'ed out values in the COUNTS attribute? I can do that ... and I suspect that "the main problem" is trawling through 50,000 lines of an array one at a time. But not sure how to do it faster...

$SQL_Results is just a regular array (my result set from SQL of the SQL query I shot to it). If you're looking for the "GetType()" information output, here you go (I'll add it once I've run it - environment just getting patch rebooted - yay).

Comment: Nothing so fancy as that -- I was just asking how fast the `for() {}` loop was with no body at all, so you have the guarantee that it's constructing the hash that's the slow bit, and not evaluating the loop. But if it's already an array, then as you say that shouldn't matter. At the same time, if it's an array then your `@($SQL_Results)` operators are unnecessary, hence my confusion.

Comment: For starters I'd try `foreach ($r in $SQL_Results) {$MyIndexHash[$r.DeviceName] = $r.Count}`.

Comment: The only other significant effort in filling a hashtable is reallocating it. That you can eliminate by setting the initial capacity: `$myIndexHash = New-Object Hashtable $SQL_Results.Count`. I doubt this has an order of magnitude improvement, though.

Comment: To add to what Ansgar said: instead of getting `$SQL_Results` from SQL into an array that you then have to process *again*, how about filling the hash table directly ([from an `SqlDataReader`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50582924/4137916)) and skipping the array business? That's one large array that doesn't need allocating and enumerating taken out of the equation.

Comment: I wasn't aware of SQLDataReader - I shall look into that!

As for "Keys are not settable" (Jeroen Mostert) .. actually they seem to be. Constructing a Hashtable and then running 

$MyHash.GetType()

... doesn't change after a 

$MyHash.Keys = $MyArray.MyValue

... running a $MyHash.GetType() - still shows it as a Hashtable, and if you just do a "$MyHash" you see all of the key-values listed. Just the data values aren't assigned  / are all null.

Comment: As another note - I had considered that "increasing the size of the hashtable" was part of the issue (turned out it wasn't) such as when dealing with larger arrays and using the "+=" operator.

But even front-loading the Hash-table with the relevant KEYS values (which again, took no time really), it was the assigning of the values (/looping through the array) that took the time.

I'll dig into the SQLDATAREADER link and play with that. Thanks (and shall report back how the findings go) :)

Comment: I didn't say keys aren't settable -- I said that assigning the `.Keys` property does not do what you think it does. Try `$a = @{}; $a.Keys = @(1, 2, 3)` and then check `$a.Count`. If you could set keys directly this way, the result would be `3`, but the result is actually `1`, because the statement is equivalent to `$a.Add("Keys", @(1, 2, 3))`. Confusingly, your new `Keys` entry is going to shadow the existing `Keys` collection (it's still accessible with `$a.PSBase.Keys`). PowerShell does not present this situation in a very intuitive way, so confusion is almost inevitable.

Comment: Ahh - thanks for clarifying, Jeroen. OK - yes, now I see the risk that you were pointing out. Lesson learned & much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect that performance bottlenecks are outside hashtable. I measured most frequent methods I saw and here are the results:

```
#demo data
#$src = 1..200000 | % { [pscustomobject]@{Name="Item_$_";Count=$_} }

#1
$timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
$hash1 = @{}
$src | % {$hash1[$_.Name]=$_.Count}
$timer.Stop()
$timer.ElapsedMilliseconds

#2
$timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
$hash2 = @{}
for ($i=0; $i -lt $src.Count; $i++) {
    $hash2.Add($src[$i].Name,$src[$i].Count)
}
$timer.Stop()
$timer.ElapsedMilliseconds

#3
$timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
$hash3 = @{}
foreach ($i in $src.GetEnumerator()) { $hash3[$i.Name] = $i.Count }
$timer.Stop()
$timer.ElapsedMilliseconds

#4
$timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
$hash3 = @{}
foreach ($i in $src) { $hash3[$i.Name] = $i.Count }
$timer.Stop()
$timer.ElapsedMilliseconds
```

It took ~5s, ~1.7s, ~0.7s, ~0.7s on my computer to complete sections 1-4 respectively (200000 records). If I had to optimize further, I would measure some native .NET methods for constructing dictionaries.

Try to optimize the rest of your code. Hints:

- are you sure all records are in memory before your hastable loop
  begins?
- are you sure properties are simple types (int, string - beware
  proxies, properties with "hidden" code)?

Comment: I would expect all my records to be in memory with the code as is (SQL only nees about 1/2 a second to give me back all of my results) ... and I've no problems accsesing the array / can list it happily.

The properties (at this point) are simple types. I was intentionally trying to keep things simple for the "index hashes", so that I can do quick lookups whether my "larger array" has "specific value X" somewhere and (if so) where it is. It should all be just INT's and Strings (unless SQL injects me some hidden stuff unexpectedly).

How would I check for any hidden elements? (And thanks :D)

Comment: Pawel Dyl - so I've run your demo-code and it's running very fast indeed . about 2-ish seconds ... and there's nothing obvious that it does differently. So that's interesting.

I'll start digging at the datatypes that SQL gives me back or see if I can find/figure any "hidden" items out ... at least things "should be MUCH faster" than the 300+ seconds I've been seeing. Very useful sanity check :)

Comment: OK - so this helped me narrow down where the problem was coming from. I was able to crank down the duration of my stuff from 400+ seconds down to under 1 second via a simple change (and using your code as basis for doing comparisons).

I will edit my initial post to highlight where the problem was (in short, it was the use of @() around the array within the loop). So I'll mark this answer as "my answer" since it lead me down the right place "the most" / the fastest (but I'll still be checking into DataReader options)!

Answer (score 4):

**Note:** I would strongly, *strongly* recommend you not use `Count` as the name of your output column since that collides with a default property in PowerShell.  Example: `@().Count` returns `0`.  Your code may work, but it's extremely ambiguous.  Changing your query to use `DeviceCount` or similar is highly recommended.

---

About the absolute fastest you're going to get this in PowerShell is by doing everything with an SqlDataReader and looping through the output directly.  Assuming your data source is SQL Server:

```
$ConnectionString = 'Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=True' -f $SqlServer, $Database
$SqlConnection = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection]::new($ConnectionString)
$SqlCommand = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand]::new($SqlQuery, $SqlConnection)

$Data = @{}
$SqlConnection.Open()
try {
    $DataReader = $SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
    while ($DataReader.Read()) {
        $Data[$DataReader.GetString(0)] = $DataReader.GetInt32(1)
    }
}
finally {
    $SqlConnection.Close()
    $SqlConnection.Dispose()
}
```

On my system, I can fetch and process 160,000 records in about 700 ms (bear in mind that I'm not using an aggregate function).

Using `$Data.Add($DataReader.GetString(0), $DataReader.GetInt32(1))` syntax instead of `$Data[$DataReader.GetString(0)] = $DataReader.GetInt32(1)` is about 20% slower for me.  However, this method does have an important caveat.  `$HashTable.Add($Key, $Value)` will throw an error on a duplicate key.  `$HashTable[$Key] = $Value` will just silently replace the value.  Ensure your SQL query is correct and won't return duplicate values

You could also use `$DataReader['DeviceName']` instead of `$DataReader.GetString(0)`, but this means the SqlDataReader would have to do a lookup so it's slightly slower (about 10%).  The drawback of using the GetX() methods is that a) the argument `0` and `1` refer to the column order, so you have to know the column order of the output (not usually a big deal) and b) you have to know the data type of the output (also usually not a big deal).

I did not see a significant performance difference using a Dictionary instead of a HashTable on the first run, but after the first run it was about 20% faster to use a Dictionary.  That is, run cold I see no difference.  Run hot I see Dictionary running faster.  You may wish to test.  If so, instead of using `$Data = @{}`, use this:

```
$InitialSize = 51000 # The more accurate this guess is without going under, the better
$Data = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[String,Int32]]::new($InitialSize)
```

---

For further reference, if you have a need to do faster lookups against an SQL result set where your lookups *do* have duplicate lookup values, it's [usually fastest to use a DataView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataview-performance), which, when sorted, does use an index for searching:

```
$ConnectionString = 'Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=True' -f $SqlServer, $Database
$SqlConnection = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection]::new($ConnectionString)
$SqlCommand = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand]::new($SqlQuery, $SqlConnection)

$DataTable = [System.Data.DataTable]::new()
$SqlConnection.Open()
try {
    $DataReader = $SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
    $DataTable.Load($DataReader)
}
finally {
    $SqlConnection.Close()
    $SqlConnection.Dispose()
}

$DataView = [System.Data.DataView]::new($DataTable)
$DataView.Sort = 'DeviceName' # Create an index used for Find() and FindRows()
$DataView.Find('DEVICE_1') # -1 means not found, otherwise it's the index of the row
$DataView.FindRows('DEVICE_1')
```

You can use an DataAdapter or a DataSet; I've just chosen to use just a DataTable here since I have code that already does it.

Comment: I'm using distinct records in my SQL query / count due to Hashtables inability of handling duplicates (which alternates between being a good thing & a headache at times, but it is a thing that makes sense at the end of the day).

I shall give this a go & see how that goes. Thanks a lot for your advice here.

I'll also make sure to rename the column to "CountOf" or something. Very valid point about not wanting to confuse either PowerShell or "future code viewers" about what is what.

Thanks & I shall report back next week :)

Comment: Hmm - regarding the "initialise" - that's not a problem in ters of accuracy. That'd be just a "select distinc count ..." result from SQL really to front-load this. I've not seen much of a difference between front-loading hashtables, but if that helps with the data, I've got no issues with "2x running" my queries in effect to get the line-count & the actual data separately.

Thanks for that tip & the education! :)

Comment: @Ygramul It's probably not worth it to fire off a query to get a count.  It's a relatively minor optimization, so the additional query is probably more costly in terms of time.

Comment: Big thanks on the suggestions here - I'll be looking at the DataReader approach for future improvements to this code. Ended up not needing to 2x fire the query since I could just have a simple Integer give me the length of the result-set & thus give me the size of the hashtable I needed to create (though no really noticable change in speed here).

I'm marking the other answer as "correct" (though I'd like to do so for this one too) since that helped me chase down "the error of my ways/code" -- but your suggestions will help me with future improvements. :)